# why php datetime object compared with comparision operator

Tags: php

php compare two dateTime object with comparision perator which is >(greater than).Below code is given

```
    $date1=new DateTime("07-03-2010");
    $date2=new Datetime("21-09-2015");
    if($date1>$date2)
    {
       echo "two datetime object has compared";
     }
```

Above code give correct result.My question is how two Datetime object is compared with comparision operator in php

Comment: Above code prints nothing. The first object output is not greater than the second one. All object attributes are compared. Since only `public 'date'` is different, it is compared as is - a string. So it compares the string '2010-03-07 00:00:00' with the string '2015-09-21 00:00:00'

Comment: @RoyalBg That's not true. Try to compare $date1 with a string "07-03-2010" - it will give false

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is a builtin and can overload operators. (This isn’t possible in PHP… yet.)

I think the relevant line is [ext/date/php_date.c:1995](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9365967dfd459b2546048c3ddfbceae9a2ee73bc/ext/date/php_date.c#L1995).

Comment: Why does this: `if($date1 > "ZZ-ZZ-ZZZZ")` give true? Using $date1 from OP example.

Comment: Yes, probably they are both casted to int

Answer (score 1):

[By design](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Built-in classes can define its own comparison

Answer (score 0):

Actually in PHP, when we store dates in a variable, it doesn't stored in any format. rather it is stored in seconds i.e. the difference between your given date and a reference date that is defined by PHP. I don't exactly remember the reference date, you may google it.

So, when you compare dates, it actually compares seconds.

Look at this,

http://codepad.org/UvbPdpmG

Comment: `mktime` doesn’t return a `DateTime` object.